# Can't view FILENAME.rhtml but can view FILENAME.html

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I receive the following error message:

> Missing template app/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en],
>   :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
>   * "/home/paul/Projects/Ruby on Rails/mark_hughes_seo_project/app/views"

It looks like it's expecting the html format. How to I instruct it look for an .rhtml file?
I've looked all over and can't seem to find an answer!

Thx,
Paul

ps. If I rename the file to .html, it works. However, I'm trying to figure out why .rhtml doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use .html.erb.  are you accessing an action on a route mapped to the application controller?  if so, that's probably not the best idea.

basically, the files go in the "app/views/#{controller_name}/#{action_name}.html.erb"
if that makes any sense.

of course, .html.haml if using haml.